# Authorise users for oneDrive without asking username/password

Tags: active-directory, oauth-2.0, office365, onedrive, office365api

I have a web applications and I wanted to allow users to pick file from oneDrive and submit those files. So my question is that, is there a way for me to allow for users who use my site to do this without asking them to log in for oneDrive ?.

I have a similar experience in googledrive and in there, we can do this through service account by authentication each users from the backend silently each time.

Further more, I have sign up for office 365 for business and link it to Azure and in there add few user to it via Active Directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a designated account to create refresh token that has 'offline access' to the OneDrive.  The offline access refresh token has a very long (or indefinite) expiry.  Use OAuth 2.0 to create the refresh token.

Every time a user needs to browse the OneDrive, use the refresh token to request a short-term access token (again, this is OAuth 2.0).  You can use that access token to access the OneDrive.

Unfortunately, my finding is that offline tokens have full read/write access - read only access doesn't seem possible.